# Need to fix x-axis and y-axis for a graph so that I can clearly see the representation

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have the image being produced as an output in python(spyder). The numbers on y-axis are all cluttered, and it is impossible to read them. How can make the graph such that every number on that y-axis is clear to read. I would also want to change the length of x-axis, so that a user can get an idea of what value each bar corresponds to on the x-axis. It is really hard to read at this point.

So, yes I do want to change both the x-axis and y-axis in their own ways as I mentioned above. Please help me with this. I am using import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, so please don't change that. Please follow the link below for the image of the graph I am getting.

http://i57.tinypic.com/6g8obb.png

Here is the code:

```
tempArray = myNumpRead[:,1]
barh = plt.subplot(111)
width = 0.8
barh.barh(range(len(states)), tempArray)
barh.set_ylim(-width,len(states)+width)
barh.set_yticks(np.arange(len(states)) + width/2)
barh.set_yticklabels(states, rotation=0)
plt.title('Population by State')
plt.xlabel('Population')
plt.ylabel('State Ticker')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Thank You for the help.

Comment: How about showing us your code? Or shall we re-create it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to answer because your code is not reproducible without your variables and I cannot see the picture in the link you provided.

However, increasing the width of your figure may be what you are asking for. This can be done as so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = x**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3)) # the 10 here is width, the 3 is height
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show(fig)
```

Let me know if this helps. If you would like further help please post code that can reproduce your problem without us requiring your variables. ie. write code that can run stand alone.

### Edit after seeing picture

Does changing your code to the following fix your issue?

```
tempArray = myNumpRead[:,1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 15)) # Change these numbers here to suit what you want
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
width = 0.8
ax.barh(range(len(states)), tempArray)
ax.set_ylim(-width,len(states)+width)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(states)) + width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(states, rotation=0)
ax.set_title('Population by State')
ax.set_xlabel('Population')
ax.set_ylabel('State Ticker')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show(fig)
```

Comment: I have updated my answer now that I have seen your picture. Still difficult to help seeing as I can't actually use the code you have provided without variables.

Comment: barh.subplot(111)    <--- Error :  "'Figure' object has no attribute 'subplot'" . I wish I could post the code, but I can't because it is for my class.

Comment: There, sorry that was a typo on my behalf. Try again. You are capable of creating an example piece of code which might be different to yours, however it replicates the problem.

Comment: That doesn't work. New error: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'barh'  <-- barh.barh(range(len(states)), tempArray)

Comment: Great !! that does work. How do I increase the limit of the population axis, so that I can see all the bars. For some states, the bars are just invisible because their pop. small compare to other states.

Comment: For me to answer you, I want you to do three things. Mark this question as answered. Create a new question, and this time structure your question in the following way: "This is what I would like to do", "This is a piece of code that works standalone that gives an example of what I have tried", "This is what I am trying to change". Do that, and I might answer it.

Comment: That's the last thing I want. Writing a code for just that would be useless. I mean you already were able to figure it out on here. So, let's just finish it here.

Comment: I got it !! Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: By the way, one stream of income for me is tutoring this stuff.  If you find yourself in a stuck feel free to give me a holla (I charge $35 US / hour).